# Return null from ToList() if list is empty?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a concise way to return a list - or null if the list is empty?

```
var list = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 2, 4, 4 };

return list.Where(x => x == 3).ToList(); //returns 0 if empty - want to return null
```

I can do this:

```
var list = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 2, 4, 4 };

var newList = list.Where(x => x == 3).ToList();
return (newList.Any()) ? newList : null;
```

but is it possible to get a null directly from the LINQ query similar to FirstOrDefault but for a list?

`list.Where(x => x == 3).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: There is no built in way, but please don't return null where a list is expected.

Comment: You can write your extension method to do that. But what's the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: I I strongly advise against doing this unless having a good reason (storing a null db field for example). Testing if a list is empty is much better than having a null to deal with in such a case here: it is cleaner, clearer and it avoids a lot of hassle, problems and errors.

Comment: That is a good point, which I will have to consider. My reason for doing it was because it's easier to assign with `list ??= anotherList` instead of using `list = list.Any() ? list : anotherList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what are your requirements to return `null` when your list is empty, but you can write your extension method to do that:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    public static List<T> NullIfEmpty<T>(this List<T> list) => 
        list.Any() ? list : null;
    
    // this will be more optimal solution
    public static List<T> ToListOrNullIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) =>
        collection.Any() ? collection.ToList() : null;

}
```

Usage:

```
list.Where(x => x == 3).ToList().NullIfEmpty();
```

or

```
list.Where(x => x == 3).ToListOrNullIfEmpty();
```

Comment: `List<T> ToListOrNullIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)` will be more optimized, isn't it? Thus: `list.Where(x => x == 3).ToListOrNullIfEmpty();`

Comment: @OlivierRogier yes, I was thinking about whether to add that to the answer or not.

Comment: Thanks. The only reason I want to return null is because it's easier to assign with with `list ??= anotherList` instead of using `list = list.Any() ? list : anotherList`. Is it bad practice to do so?

Comment: I'd suggest doing `list?.Any() ?? false ? list : null` to handle the case that `list` itself is null.

Comment: Note: iterating a sequence twice is unreliable; most inbuilt LINQ operators deliberately avoid this - see my answer for "how"

Answer (score 4):

A fun but often overlooked feature of sequences (`IEnumerable<T>`) is that you're **only meant to enumerate them once** - so anything that involves a `.Any()` check or similar, is not *strictly* reliable (although for many data sources: you'll get away with it). But to be pure, you'd want to do something like (to extend the answer given [by SᴇM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67518517/23354):

```cs
static class MyExtensions
{    
    // this will be more optimal solution
    public static List<T> ToListOrNullIfEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        using (var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!iter.MoveNext()) return null;
            var list = new List<T>();
            do
            {
                list.Add(iter.Current);
            }
            while (iter.MoveNext())
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

You could of course optimize this with type-tests on some known types, like `List<T>`, `T[]`, `IList<T>`, etc - if you choose.

Comment: +1. This should be accepted answer. Especially if source enumerable involves sorting, taking Any() can trigger big operation.